# CSS: a:hover img no background?

Tags: css, hover

I have a background color on my links (on hover, rails-style). And I have an img inside an a-tag that I don't want to have a background on hover.

I tried

```
a:hover img{ background-color: #fff; }
```

but that's not doing anything. How do I exclude img-tags inside a-tags from the hover?

Thx,
MrB

edit: jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rasvf/1/

In the example: "google" has a red background on hover, as intended. But when you hover over the image, it also does. It's supposed not to have a hover background.

Comment: By not including them in the first place?

Comment: You're missing a : in your example there, is it a typo? `a:hover img{ background-color: #fff; }`

Comment: Oh, the : I forgot. It's there in my code, though. What's a jsFiddle?

Comment: Myth: How do I not include them in the first place?

Comment: @MrB: look at http://jsfiddle.net/. You can publish your example source code, so the others can better understand your concept, problems, etc.

Comment: @MrB the context of the `<a>` is important. Does the parent element have a `background-color`? More importantly, what format is the image saved as. You cannot set a transparent background on JPG images, for example. This could explain why @netbrain's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qwJy/) works as it uses a PNG with a transparent background and your site does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I did it. Easy. I just put the not-to-have-a-background-image in a different div and then did:

```
.otherdiv a:hover{ background-color: transparent; }
```

Answer (score 2):

if i understand you correctly, i think you are trying to do something like this:

```
a:hover img{ visibility: hidden; }
```

or

```
a:hover img{ display: none; }
```

**EDIT**

In that case you want:

```
a:hover img {background-color: transparent;}
```

Example posted on: http://jsfiddle.net/6qwJy/

Comment: Sorry, no. I just want the image to have no mouseover-background, like I want the links to have.

Comment: a:hover img{ 
    background-color: transparent;
  }

Comment: That's what I typed, but it isn't working. Image still has a background on hover.

Comment: `background-color:transparent` is only [partially implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx#colors) in IE6 so this solution will not work for that browser.

Comment: IE6 is, as far as i am concerned. dead and buried.

Comment: @netbrain you may think that, but it is naïve to assume that the OP does not want a solution that works in IE6. It doesn't sound like you worked for a company that still needs IE6 support and either relies on it for corporate applications or in dropping support for it would lose millions of potential sales/customers. Unfortunately this is still the case for many organisations. I dislike IE6 as much as anyone but you have to be pragmatic about which features will be hacked in or worked around in IE6 and which can be implemented as _progressive enhancement_.

Comment: You are quite wrong in your assumption that i have not worked in a company that still needs IE6. But i believe that we as web developers need to force the use of newer browsers. And dont build in support for old browsers that doesn't even follow the web standards. It is in my opinion the only way to make sure that the web development plattform keeps moving forward! my 5 cents..

Comment: @andyb: It's sensible (in this day and age) to assume that IE6 support is not required unless it's explicitly asked for in the question. Maybe add a note if it will go *horribly wrong* in IE6. More to the point, the `background-color: transparent` will (I guess) work in IE6 in this case. It's the `a:hover img` selector that definitely won't.

Comment: @thirtydot: yes, I agree. I do try and add a note if things will not work in particular browsers which is the point I was trying to get across in my original comment. As it currently exists this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6qwJy/) does not work in IE6 but does work in IE7+

Comment: @andyb: It turns out I was a little wrong in my reasoning (of *why* it wasn't working). This works in IE6. Make of it what you will: http://fiddle.jshell.net/kp4ZK/show/light/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand your example. Say I have this piece of HTML:

```
<a class="foo" href="#"><img src="bar.gif"/> Click me</a>
```

then with these style rules

```
a#foo:hover { background-color: blue; }
a#foo img { background-color: white; }
```

the image background color will always be white, also on hover.

If however you have background images on the element that contains your link and you want that to show behind the foreground image, then you can't do this. In that case you'll have to wrap the "Click me" text of the link in a span and write in your stylesheet:

```
a#foo:hover span { background-color: blue; }
```

Is this what you intended?

Comment: Close. The 'click me' text and the img-tag are not in the same a-tag. I want text in a-tags to have a:hover-background-color, but not img-tags in a-tags.

Comment: @MrB In that case, add a class attribute to the <a> tags that wrap an image so you can select them specifically, e.g. <a class="clickableimage" href="#"><img src="logo2.png"></a>. If you can't change the html then try javascript $('a img').parent(). Then you can write in your style sheet a[class^='clickableimage']:hover { background-color:red; } or something...

Comment: I made a mistake in prev comment. I meant to say: if you can't change the html then try $('a img').parent() in javascript to find the <a> tags that wrap an image, then add the class name programatically. Finally you can write in your style sheet a:not(.clickableimage):hover { background-color:red; } to specifically target just the <a> without image.

Answer (score 0):

```
a img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: you are supposed to  describe your answer ..only giving the link or code is not a good technique

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you won't believe me, but I had the same problem above and I resolved as follows:

I had something like this:

`<a href="#">`
        `<img src"path/to/image.gif">`
`</a>`

And in my CSS I had:

`a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }`

And, believe me, I just had to put the 'img' tag in the same line as the 'a' tag, like this:

`<a href="#"><img src="path/to/img.gif"></a>`

And that was all!!!